# ES6 Syntax for Angular .config() and run()

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to convert my app to use ES6 Syntax and in my main module i have config and run invocations.

I changed them to

```
import * as angular from 'angular';
import {config,run} from './my-config';
import MyAppController from './my-app-controller';

module.exports = angular.module("my-app", [])

    .config(config)

    .run(run)

    .controller('myAppController', MyAppController)
```

and here is my-config.js

```
import MyService from './my-service';
export function config($compileProvider, $logProvider, localStorageServiceProvider,$stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

    console.log('.config() : START ');
    $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(true);

    $logProvider.debugEnabled(true);

    localStorageServiceProvider.setPrefix('myapp');
    localStorageServiceProvider.setNotify(true, true);

    $stateProvider.state('home', {
        url: '/',
        views: {
            'main': {
                controller: 'myAppCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'app/home.tpl.html'
            }
        }
    });
    // handle routes here
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
}
config.$inject =['$compileProvider', '$logProvider', 'localStorageServiceProvider','$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];



export function run(MyService) {
    console.log('.run() : ');
    MyService.start();
 }

 run.$inject=['MyService'];
```

And config and run functions are not getting invoked..

Please let me know what i am missing

Thanks

Comment: The regular version of Angular 1.x doesn't export anything, so `import * as angular from 'angular';` can't work.

Comment: i replaced module.exports with export default and and it is not throwing any Error. (Earlier i was using old version of node and npm and not sure whether that caused the error i was getting when i used export default).

Answer (score 5):

Few things I suggest:

```
import angular from 'angular';

export default angular
  .module('app', [
    //list of your modules
  ])
  .config(config)
  .run(run)
  .name;
```

Config we use:

```
export default function config(/* injectables here */) {
  //Your code
}
```

Run we use:

```
export default function run(/* injectables here */) {
 /* @ngInject */
 //Your code
}
```

You might not use the injectables like we do, or use /* @ngInject */

Comment: How does this solve the problem? Angular 1.x is not ES6, so  how is `import angular from 'angular';` supposed to work out of the box? Where are the imports for `config` and `run`? Why split `my-config.js` into two? What's the point of exporting the module's name?

Comment: I have split the conf into two files. Earlier i didn't have "export default" as it was not allowing if i put two functions in the same file. Now i have split them into two files and each has export default. How ever after all this i still don't see the run or config methods getting called at all !!

Comment: My Issue seems be the $inject is not working.  The call is going to run() method how ever nothing is getting injected into run() or config() methods.

Comment: Here is the github repo for the sample project i created https://github.com/mars76/angular-es6.git

Comment: Thanks everyone . I am able to resolve the issue. I didn't have ui-router in my package.json and needed to create a module to inject services into the run function.

Answer (score 1):

Bellow I'll write an example explain how to write with ES6 and Angularjs the syntax of Config.

we suppose that our bootstrap module named : `main` so we need to add this module

**main.js**

```
import angular   from 'angular';
import ngRoute   from 'angular-route';
import MainRoute from './main.route';//import config rout whuch I added in //other js file
    let mainModule =
        angular.module('mainApp', [
                'ngRoute',
                homeModule.name,
            ]

        )
        .config(MainRoute);

    export default mainModule;
```

**main.route.js**

```
  export default  function routeConfig($routeProvider) {

            $routeProvider
                .when('/', {
                    templateUrl: 'src/content.components/home/home.tpl.html',
                    controller: 'HomeController as vm'
                });
        }

    routeConfig.$inject = ["$routeProvider"];
```